# How do I view RSS feeds as formatted XML?

Tags: xml, rss

Is there a way to view rss feeds as formatted xml that doesn't involve messing with my browser's installation or writing my own tool?

Edit:

Preferably a way that works on an OS other than Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Code Beautify's RSS Viewer is a tool to view RSS feed as XML as well as in HTML format: http://codebeautify.org/rssviewer/

Click on Load, enter RSS feed URL and it will output XML data on the left side and HTML data on the right side. This tool also supports to convert RSS XML to JSON.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, the HTML view is always blank. (on Chrome)

Answer (score 2):

[XML Notepad](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=72D6AA49-787D-4118-BA5F-4F30FE913628&displaylang=en) does a decent job for the right price (free).

You can also drag-drop the file into Chrome and press CTRL+U.

You can also use CMD + Opt + U on a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

If you view the feed in Firefox it'll read like an RSS reader, but if you view the source code you've got it in XML format.  And you can get both on MAC (if that's the OS you're referring to).

Comment: I know I can view the source, but it's not formated, like firefox usually displays xml. It's impossible to read xml produced by google since it comes striped of whitespace. I'm refering to any OS, except windows, since I'm using about 4 of them including mac and solaris, but not windows.

Comment: But Firefox views it like it's an RSS feed.  Does your version not do that?

Answer (score 1):

Just put Feed URL into Google Chrome, and it shows the results as XML